# Reactjs convert input string to upper case

Tags: reactjs, string

I'm creating an app in Reactjs using react-strap. I would like to convert an input field to upper case.

From googling, it looks like simply appending "toUpperCase()" to the field would work, but this doesn't appear as an option in Visual Studio code.

I had a similar issue with doing a replace all, but finally got that to work using "const" field:

```
// replace ":" with "-"
const phrase = item.macs;
const replaced = phrase.replace(/:/g, '-')
item.macs = replaced;
```

However, converting to a const field doesn't work for making the "toUpperCase()" available.

What should I do to turn this into a string so I can call the "toUpperCase()" function?

Edit: change references from "toUpper" to "toUpperCase".  The problem is this is not available as a function.

For example of I do

'myString'.toUpperCase();

it works. But it I can't get it to bring that up in Visual Studio Code, and it's ignored if I code it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To make a string uppercase in javascript you can call `.toUpperCase()` method on it. For example

```
 const foo = 'foo'
 const fooUpper = foo.toUpperCase()

 console.log(fooUpper) // expected result 'FOO'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking after [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by forcing the input item to be regarded as a string by prepending it with a '', like so:

```
item.macs = '' + item.macs;
item.macs = item.macs.replace(/:/g, '-');
item.macs = item.macs.toUpperCase();
```

After that, all the string functions were available.